# string1 >= string2 not implemented in Linq to SQL, any workaround?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, string-comparison

How do I do string1 >= string2 in Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

string1 >= string2 is not supported in C# Linq To Sql.  The String class does not override the >= operator at all.  It only overrides the != and == operators. You can verify this by trying to compile the following method

```
public static void Example() {
  int val = "foo" >= "bar";
}
```

If you want to compare to Strings in LinqToSql you should be able to use the static [String.Compare(string,string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx) method.

Comment: => isn't the same as >=, I am unsure if he is talking about a method pointer as in a delegate or an actual >=.

Comment: @Nick, it's a typo in my example.  The SO TextEditor compiler is terrible ;)

Comment: Why was this changed from >= to =>?

Answer (score 31):

If you're looking for `=>` which would normally be written as `>=` then you cannot do this directly with strings.  You can get the same behaviour via [CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compareto.aspx):

```
string1.CompareTo(string2) >= 0
```

In this case, the result being less than or equal to zero means that `string1` would be sorted before `string2` and therefore is greater.

FYI the `=>` operator in C# is only used in the definition of lambda expressions.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use a greater than or equal operator with strings, because there is not definitive way to tell what you are talking about.  If they are actually numbers you may want to do.

```
var query = from c in dc.Customers
            where c.CustomerID >= Int32.Parse("32")
            select c;
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but strings directly translate to Linq to SQL queries.

Could you give an example of what you're attempting?

Here's a basic example usage:

```
string string2 = "test";

using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
{
   // without lambdas
   var query1 = from item in dc.Items
               where item.Value == string2
               select item;

   // with lambdas
   var query2 = dc.Items.Where(item=>item.string1 == string2);
}
```