# LINQ to SQL use of => operand on String not allowed

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [string1 >= string2 not implemented in Linq to SQL, any workarround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553407/string1-string2-not-implemented-in-linq-to-sql-any-workarround)

To give a brief summary of what I want to achieve we have a table called Application and it stores application version numbers.  The contents of that Table for example is

```
ApplicationID          VersionID
1                      R1.01.01.01
2                      C8.00.00.01
2                      C8.00.00.02
2                      R8.10.00.00
2                      R8.20.00.02
2                      R9.00.00.01
2                      R9.00.00.02
2                      R9.00.00.03
3                      R7.00.30.00
```

When I am doing this query in TSQL, there are no problems and I get the correct results  (Take note that the VersionID is nvarchar type)

```
Select * From Applications where VersionID >= 'R9.00.00.01' and ApplicationID = 2
```

but when I start using LINQ to SQL like such

```
var Applications = from v in db.Applications 
                   where v.VersionID.StartsWith("R") 
                   && v.VersionID >= "R9.00.00.01" 
                   && v.ApplicationID == 2
                   orderby v.VersionID
                   select v;
```

Then I get the error "Operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

How do I achive that in LINQ to SQL without changing anything on the database side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`string.Compare()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx)?

```
&& string.Compare( v.VersionID , "R9.00.00.01"  ) >= 0
```

Comment: i just wrote the same answer, but i think this is being translated to SQL....that won't work will it?

Comment: @Mark I'm always a little fuzzy on how it translates. This is my best guess and I'll take eat the down arrows if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
string.Compare(v.VersionID, "R9.00.00.01") >= 0
```

instead